# YouTube analytics and data API data retention duration

Tags: .net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to pull Youtube data using analytics and data API within this time range 2017-07-01 and 2018-07-01.
For 2017, it's returning no data. What is the YouTube analytics and data API data retention duration ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull YouTube analytics data all the way back to a video's upload date. YouTube isn't removing any kind of view data from the past.

I've verified this on my account with videos from 7 years ago.